# What is the name of the small circuit board above the trackpad that the flex cable connects to on the MacBook pro retina 2015 13"?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, trackpad, repair, logicboard

My keyboard and track pad are not working and I'm thinking it's neither the keyboard nor the track pad nor even the flex cable. When I was replacing the flex cable the circuit board that the flex cable connect to (from the logic board) short and sparked - somehow I'd forgotten to turn of the laptop.

This is the small board located below the battery above the track pad on the MacBook Pro Retina 2015 13". I guess I need to replace that board. But I don't know what it's called. Does anyone here know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places where the track pad connects - the logic board (red) arrow and to the track pad PCB (red square)

[image: Track pad PCB]
<sup>Image Source:  [Ifixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Early+2015+Trackpad+Replacement/45138)</sup>

If what you're referring to is what's identified by the red square at the bottom of the image above, then it's the PCB. It's  not sold as a separate assembly (AFAIK) and you have to replace the entire track pad assembly ([PN# 923-00518](http://radnex.us/trackpad_MBP-2015-13inch_923-00518)). If it's the top portion (red arrow), you have to get the logic board repaired/replaced.

It's possible you could buy a salvaged track pad from eBay just to get the PCB, but it's an "unknown."  You could end up getting a track pad with a bad PCB again, but if the price is good, it may be worth the gamble.

Finally, if you got a spark when connecting the flex cable, replace the flex cable as well.  When you see a spark, that means enough voltage passed through the cable to arc which could have permanently damaged the cable - it's cheap enough that you should just do it anyway and not try to salvage a cable of questionable function.